# PHP submit form on same page with echo shown below form

Tags: php, forms

I'm aware that this question has been asked a huge number of times but the answers seem really specific to the script posted and with my current knowledge I can't make the transition from the corrected script to implementing it into my own.

This all works fine - it submits on the same page and provides feedback of any errors, but I want any errors to be echoed beneath the form making it more convenient for the user to just change what they entered incorrectly and re-submit.

From what I can gather from the questions I read before posting this - it may only be possible using jQuery/Ajax?

My script:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
require "connection.php";

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$repeat_password = $_POST["repeat_password"];

$username_query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
$email_query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");

if($username == "" || $password == "" || $repeat_password == "" || $email == ""){
  die("All boxes must be filled out!");
}// ^ Checking if all boxes have been filled out
else {
    if (!ctype_alnum($username)){
        die("Username can only contain letters and numbers");
    }// ^ Checking if username is alphanumeric
    else {
        if (strlen($username) < 6 || strlen($username) > 15){
            die("Username must be between 6-15 characters.");
        }// ^ Checking if username is between 6-15 characters
        else {
            if (mysql_num_rows($username_query) != 0){
                die("Username is taken, please choose another.");
            }// ^ Checking if username exists in database
            else {
                if (!preg_match("/[0-9]/",$password)){
                    echo "password doesnt contain a number";
                    }
                else {
                    if ($password != $repeat_password){
                        die("Passwords do not match");
                    }// ^ Checking if password and repeat_password match
                    else {
                        if (strlen($password) < 6){
                            die("Password must be atleast 6 characters long.");
                        }// ^ Checking if password is longer than 6 characters
                        else {
                            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                                die("E-mail address is not vaild.");
                            }// ^ Checking if e-mail address is valid
                            else {
                                if (mysql_num_rows($email_query) != 0){
                                    die("This e-mail address has already been used to create a different account.");
                                }// ^ Checking if e-mail address has already been used
                                else {
                                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, signup_date) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email', CURDATE())") or die(mysql_error());
                                    echo "Account succesfully created, welcome ".$username."!";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
exit;
}

// 

?>

        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Username:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="username">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Password:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="password" name="password">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Repeat password:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="password" name="repeat_password">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        E-mail:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="email" name="email">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <center><input type="submit" name="submit"></center>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:** Yes, you have to use jQuery there.

You can validate form just after user entered 1st letter. You can validate on key up/down or on submit. I suggest to use [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

To sumbit form use ajax requests. It is rly simple. You can read about it [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). There are some examples at the end page I had given.

Note, that if you will use jQuery Validation Plugin you can send ajax request on `valid` action. Using this, ajax request with serialized form will be sent on form submit + on form valid. If form has some invalid fields, errors will be shown, if there are no errors, ajax-request will be send.

**Advice**: 
Your arhitecture not very good. Why? If people will write bad name and make 10 more other errors, only 1 error:

> Username can only contain letters and numbers

will be shown. Why? Because of you arhitecture. After that he will correct 2nd erorr. 3rd error etc.

I suggest you do to handle errors this way:

```
$errors = array();
$errorsFlag = false;

if(check_username1()) {
    $errors[] = 'Tell about this error';
    $errorsFlag = true;
}

if(check_username2()) {
    $errors[] = 'Tell about this error';
    $errorsFlag = true;
}
if(check_mail()) {
    $errors[] = 'Tell about this error';
    $errorsFlag = true;
}
```

And how to output it? Use this:

```
if($errorsFlag == true) {
    foreach($errors as $error) {
        echo $error . " <br /> ";;
    }    
}
```

Comment: I hadn't actually thought about that - can you suggest a way in which this can be improved?

Comment: I see this is similar to another answer - but it just confused me. This makes it a lot clearer, I'll adapt this method and see what I can come up with. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I always set my errors as a session. This allows you to set multiple errors at once, and print them wherever you want.

The following if statements are just examples of where you would set the errors...

```
session_start(); //you will need this

if ( username_exists($un) ) {

    handleError("Username already exists!");

}
```

...

```
if ( !passwordIsStrong($pw) ) {

    handleError("Password is not strong enough!");

}
```

Here's the functions that actually set/print the errors.

```
function handleError( $err ) {

    //get any existing errors
    $existing = isset($_SESSION['form-errors']) ? $_SESSION['form-errors'] : '';

    //append the new error to the existing ones. Over-write the session with new data.
    $_SESSION['form-errors'] = "$existing<li>$err</li>";

}

function getErrors() {

    if( isset($_SESSION['form-errors']) )

         echo $_SESSION['form-errors'];


}
```

`getErrors();` can be called anywhere in your html. It will print something like this...

`<li>Username already exists!</li>`
`<li>Password is not strong enough!</li>`

It's kind of like a log. But it's worked for me on all of my projects!

Answer (score 0):

yes, you'll need `javascript`. but not necessarily `jQuery` or `ajax`.

but `php` without the use of `ajax` always needs you to reload the page cause otherwise the php-code will not be executed.

search for some kind of javascript/jQuery validation scripts if you don't want the page to be reloaded. otherwise (if you don't care about page-reloading), you can put out your error message at the end of the form with php as well.